# How to set "./configure --without-iconv" in Eclipse (CDT)?

Tags: c, eclipse, configure, eclipse-cdt

I'm with this error: "undefined reference to 'libiconv_open'" While compiling
On this site there is a solution:
[[SOLVED] Error "undefined reference to 'libiconv_open'" while compiling](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/12/06/solved-error-undefined-reference-to-libiconv_open-while-compiling/)

But, I'm using Eclipse CDT + MingW to compile, and I have not found where to put the variables ./configure --without-iconv

Could anyone help me?

I'm using Eclipse Juno + CDT + Windows 7 + MingW

(Sorry my poor english xD, i'm brazilian...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed to include that library?

`#include <libiconv_open>`

Comment: It is not necessary ....
The need to include is # include <iconv.h> ...

I'm trying to compile [unac](http://www.nongnu.org/unac/unac-man3.en.html)

But these errors appear
"undefined reference to` libiconv_open '
undefined reference to `libiconv '
undefined reference to `libiconv_close '"

And to solve, need to put the ./configure --without-iconv in eclipse ... =/

Comment: I've never seen something like that, sorry, but I can't help :\